# Answer deleted; what went wrong?

Tags: discussion

Sorry for posting this as a question, but there seems to be no way to contact the administrator.

Yesterday I posted an answer to a question. My answer was deleted and I was linked to a copy off the rules. I feel that my answer complied to the rules and was also technically correct. Please clarify what the problem was.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not know why your answer was deleted, but looking at your track record: in general its good practice not to dig up and answer questions which are over a year old and already have answers. Please keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: You should use the meta site for this as this question is related to the running / workings of the site rather than maintenance or repair. Closing as off topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

Firstly, questions about the running of the site live here in the 'meta' side - I've migrated this one. There isn't really an administrator as such, the site is run by the community itself, and the moderators (me, Paulster2 and Bob Cross) help out where needed.

Secondly, you posted quite a few answers yesterday, several of which were deleted as being low quality - in fact all four were automatically flagged by the system - could you let us know which one you are unhappy about?

For example, looking at [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/53249/does-cylinder-misfire-mean-buy-new-engine/53254#53254) - you state that it is most likely a cheap fix, but you don't then give any suggestions as to what it might be, or any details - so what you've posted doesn't help the person who asked. If you look at Terry Gould's answer to the same question, he gives a number of suggestions of things to try. A great answer to that question might look something like this:

> A misfire on that engine could be commonly caused by X, Y or Z, although more rarely it could also be caused by W or V.
>
> To check for X, do A, then B and C - if you then see D, you know that X has failed and needs replacing.
>
> Y is slightly harder to diagnose, as you need to do E and F, but much easier to fix if it is the cause, as you just need to G and H.
>
> ...

Similarly, you've posted two answers on OBD questions stating that OBD-II is a US standard and that EOBD is European - this may be technically correct, but it's not all that helpful to the asker - better would be to note what the differences are between them (from my understanding the two are effectively identical) and what difference, if any, it might make to a user looking to read the codes.

Generally, the best answers are those that are helpful to the community at large as well as the original asker - and one-liners often aren't, as they don't give any detail. Say what, and say why (and where applicable, how). References are good too, but don't just give links - summarise what they say as well, as links can go stale quickly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well said. If it’s useful, I’m the Bob Cross mentioned above. Nick, Paul and I work together to help the community create a positive resource. Sometimes this doesn’t mean that things get pruned. It isn’t coming from a place of meanness. It’s usually just trimming and adjusting.

Comment: And I'm the Paul in this equation. I'm the one who did the pruning. Definitely not trying to be mean. I think Nick's note does a great job of explaining what was going on. Hope to see you posting in the future ... just a little more in the StackExchange style of things! :o)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up guys.